# MVC3 Razor Webgrid with submit button - How get clicked row ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

Please suggest me regarding one issue. I am using MVC3 Razor webgrid I need 2 input submit/button [Edit/Delete] in each row. Should be button not link. Code is something like this.

```
@grid.GetHtml(columns:
grid.Columns(
grid.Column("ID", "id"),
grid.Column("Value", "Value"),
grid.Column(format: @<input type="button" value="Edit"/>),
grid.Column(format: @<input type="button" value="Delete"/>))
)
```

I have to do on server no javascript function.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use ACTION LINK here,

```
 @grid.GetHtml(columns:
 grid.Columns(
 grid.Column("ID", "id"),
 grid.Column("Value", "Value"),
 grid.Column(format: @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditAction", new { id = item.id}),
 grid.Column(format: @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteAction", new { id = item.id})
 )
```

you can then define a nice css for it to make it look like a button,
refer
http://www.dofactory.com/topic/1015/html-actionlink-and-class-attribute.aspx

Comment: Thanks Yasser, In your example you are using actionlink but I want Input button. Anyway I accomplish this by using Javascript.

Comment: Oh ! I thought you didn't wanted to use Javascript ?

Comment: My Html has no ActionLink :(

Answer (score 0):

After trying options I accomplish this using a hidden field. On click button populate hidden field with javascript and submit form using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
grid.Column(format: @<form method="get"action="/Controller/Action/@item.id">
                         <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Edit" />
                    </form>)
```

Comment: Can you please comment your answer so other people understand your answer better?